# remove item from listview and from diplay

Tags: android, listview

In my code there is a listview in which i am doing an operation to delete the listview item. it works but remains displayed in the listview. It is in the second activity.It disappears only after going to the firstactivity and then returns.Please give me the changes that i have to make.

Getclicker.java

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, final long id) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(Getclicker.this);
                    adb.setTitle("Delete?");
                    adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete the event" + (position+1));
                     final int positionToRemove = position;
                    adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

                        adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                eventsData1.delete( id);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }});
                        adb.show();
                    }
```

> delete method in database

```
public void delete(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id )});
        db.close();
    }
```

Comment: you mean ur listview is not refreshing?

Comment: yes.........................

Comment: can you post some details about `eventsData1.delete( id);`

Comment: are u useing string or ArrayList??

Comment: eventsData1  <<< what's this ? can u give us more lines of code?

Comment: Its better if u use ArrayList then it u delete item from arraylist that will help u rather than using String[]

Comment: I have given you a answer this will might hep you.

Answer (score 1):

As I see, right now you're deleting an item from Database, but you're not deleting it from adapter, that's why deleted item is still in the ListView. When you go to another activity and then go back to the listView, you load changed data in the adapter.

You should delete an item from the adapter too if you want notifyDataSetChanged() to have an effect . . .

Your code should be something like this:

```
eventsData1.delete( id);
adapter.deleteItem(id);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

add delete() method in your Adapter class . . .

Comment: there is no adapter class i have defined.i only imported it.

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting on the basis of id i.e Long Type

```
eventsData1.delete( id);
```

You should use "position"

```
eventsData1.delete(position);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Assuming op has the data layer wired up properly so the adapter reflects the current state.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned your deleting operation is working fine but the problem is in listView refreshing. Untill and unless you are changing the activity it is not refreshing your list. What you have to really do is that you have to add this piece of code at the end of the line where deleting operation is ending within onItemClick:

```
 yourListView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

Comment: OP will be notified when u have posted an answer... no need to post comment under question everytime u answers...